# Filter groups of df when each row of group fulfills the condition in at least N columns

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a small trouble with my df. Firstly I'll show you an example, then explain what I'd like to recieve.

My input df:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
A   I   I   D   X   I   I   I
A   I   I   I   X   D   I   I
A   I   I   I   X   I   I   I
A   I   D   I   X   NC  I   I
B   D   D   I   X   I   I   I
B   D   I   NC  X   I   I   D
C   NC  I   I   X   NC  D   I
C   I   I   I   X   I   I   I
C   I   I   I   X   I   I   D
D   NC  NC  I   X   D   D   D
D   I   I   I   X   D   D   I
D   D   D   I   X   I   I   NC
D   I   I   I   X   NC  I   I
E   NC  I   I   X   I   I   D
E   I   I   I   X   I   D   D
```

Desired result:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
A   I   I   D   X   I   I   I
A   I   I   I   X   D   I   I
A   I   I   I   X   I   I   I
A   I   D   I   X   NC  I   I
```

I'd like to have only groups (`group by column 'C1'`) (with all rows) where there're **at least 2** occurances of `'I'` in each row of group (let's take `A`) in group columns `C2, C3, C4` **and** `C6, C7, C8`.

I decided to use `filter()`, `all()` and `rowSums()`

```
 df_filtered <- df %>%
  group_by(C1) %>%
  filter(all(rowSums(df[,2:4] == 'I' & df[,6:8] == 'I') >= 2))
```

wht doesn't it work? It returns 0 rows, no idea why...

Comment: Why do you exclude the `C`-rows 8 and 9, and `E`-row 14? They also have at least 2 `I`'s in group columns `C2, C3, C4` and `C6, C7, C8`.

Comment: If there's one or less `I` in columns `C2, C3, C4` or `C6, C7, C8` although in one row, whole group is discarded. `C` group has `NC` and `D` in row 7, columns `C6, C7`. If we put `I` instead of `NC` or `D` or both, whole group should pass the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

```
df %>%
    mutate(condition = rowSums(.[2:4] == 'I') >= 2 & rowSums(.[6:8] == 'I') >= 2) %>%
    group_by(C1) %>%
    filter(all(condition)) %>%
    select(-condition)
```

#### Result

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   C1 [1]
      C1     C2     C3     C4     C5     C6     C7     C8
  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1      A      I      I      D      X      I      I      I
2      A      I      I      I      X      D      I      I
3      A      I      I      I      X      I      I      I
4      A      I      D      I      X     NC      I      I
```

#### Explanation

When you used

```
filter(all(rowSums(df[,2:4] == 'I' & df[,6:8] == 'I') >= 2))
```

the `all()` comparison was on *all* rows of `df`, not just the ones from your group. This approach evaluates the condition for each row, then calls `all()` only on the group.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer that I was looking for, works great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

you could try with `unite()` and then filtering by regular expressions. Here your example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# First loading your data 
data <-read.table(text = "C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
A   I   I   D   X   I   I   I
A   I   I   I   X   D   I   I
A   I   I   I   X   I   I   I
A   I   D   I   X   NC  I   I
B   D   D   I   X   I   I   I
B   D   I   NC  X   I   I   D
C   NC  I   I   X   NC  D   I
C   I   I   I   X   I   I   I
C   I   I   I   X   I   I   D
D   NC  NC  I   X   D   D   D
D   I   I   I   X   D   D   I
D   D   D   I   X   I   I   NC
D   I   I   I   X   NC  I   I
E   NC  I   I   X   I   I   D
E   I   I   I   X   I   D   D", header = T)

# Then filtering rows
data %>% 
  # Creating a helper column
  unite(merged, C1:C8, sep = "", remove = F) %>%
  # Filtering by regexp
  filter(grepl("^A", merged), grepl("II", merged)) %>%
  # Deleting helper column
  select(-merged)
```

## This is the results:

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
1  A  I  I  D  X  I  I  I
2  A  I  I  I  X  D  I  I
3  A  I  I  I  X  I  I  I
4  A  I  D  I  X NC  I  I
```

have fun ;)

Comment: This solution presupposes OP already knows only group `A` will be in the result. It also presupposes that every time there are two `I` in both of the three variable groupings, at least one of those will be consecutive. For example, it wouldn't catch a row where `merged` equaled `AIDIXIDI` even though that would match OP's condition.